# Laravel: "Login information is not registered" error when logging in with user ID

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel system where I was logged in with email and password.
This time, I want to enable login with the newly added user ID (column name: admins_id) and password.
I tried the code below, but when I try to log in, I get a validation error saying "Login information is not registered".
It seems that there is no mistake between the ID and password.
Is there anything wrong with it?
Column creation and new user inserted with phpmyadmin.

structure of admins
[image]

#### Code

app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Auth/LoginController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }
    public function username()
{
    return 'admins_id';
 }
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
 {
     $username = $request->input($this->username());
     $password = $request->input('password');

     if (filter_var($username, \FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $credentials = ['email' => $username, 'password' => $password];
     } else {
         $credentials = [$this->username() => $username, 'password' => $password];
     }
     return $this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->filled('remember'));
 }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(
            $request->only($this->username(), 'password'),
            ['area_id' => config('constants.AREA_ID')]
        );
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return $this->loggedOut($request);
    }

    public function loggedOut(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect(route('admin.login'));
    }
}
```

app/User.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'admins_id', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

resources/views/admin/auth/login.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.admin.app')

@section('main')

    <div class="l-login">
        <div class="l-login__logo"><img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/common/logo.svg') }}" alt=""><span class="area">【{{ config('constants.AREA_NAME') }}版】</span></div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="c-form__login_email">
                <input id='admins_id' type="text" name="admins_id" class="c-form__control @error('admins_id') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('admins_id') }}" autofocus>
            </div>
            {{-- <div class="c-form__login_email">
                <input type="email" name="emails" class="c-form__control" placeholder="メールアドレス" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus>
            </div> --}}
            <div class="c-form__login_password">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="c-form__control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="パスワード">
            </div>
            <div class="c-form__login_remember">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> ログイン状態を保存する</label>
            </div>
            @error('admins_id')
            <div class="c-form__invalid_feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
            @enderror
            @error('password')
            <div class="c-form__invalid_feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
            @enderror

            <div class="c-buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="c-button c-button__action">ログイン</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

@endsection
```

#### Version

Laravel: 7.16.1

Comment: did you hash the password in the database?

Comment: I see there is no username field in your database table.

Comment: @lagbox It is hashed with password_hash. However, if the hash method is wrong, I feel that "passwords do not match".

Comment: @OrkSophanin The username is entered in the admins_id column.